# Using a foreach for switch values compared to hardcoding them

Tags: php

I am allowing users to define their country when they register. I am going to use ajax and a list of countries in the database to populate the select options. Now would it be best to hard code those in to a switch:

```
switch($country):
   case 'United States':
       $usercountry = 'United States'; 
   break;
   //etc
   default: $usercountry = 'Not Set';
endswitch;
```

Or would it be better to do a foreach? For an example:

```
switch($country):

foreach($sitecountries as $countries):
   case $countries:
       $usercountry = $countries; 
   break;
   default: $usercountry = 'Not Set';
endforeach;

endswitch;
```

Is there any benifits over using one code vs the other, granted the first switch will be HUGE, so the 2nd one seems to beat it on that.

Question too broad: What is the benifits of using a foreach for a switch compared to hard coding the values in it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Display the countries? Validate the user's input?

Comment: I have javascript to make sure the countrie's set user side, it's incase they change the select value to something other than a stored country so I'm checking server side too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one may be a better option but the use of a switch could be replaced by an if so :

```
$usercountry = 'Not Set';
foreach($sitecountries as $countries){

    if($country == $usercountry){
       $usercountry = $countries; 
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use some kind of code for your countries, you can do it with an array and map them that way:

```
$countries = array(
                    'United States'=>'us',
                    'Netherlands'=>'nl'
                   );
```

To get one simply use:

```
$countries['United States'];
```

And it will output `'us'`.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't make something like :

```
if($country)
{
  $userCountry = $country;
}
else{
  $userCountry = "Not Set";
}
```

Another way to code this :

```
$userCountry = $country ?: "Not Set";
```

Comment: I've heard, maybe untrue that if statements can't be compiled with c#? If I ever plan on compiling my PHP.